# Gradle fails to create Eclipse project files

Tags: gradle

I am trying to start a new Java EE project with Gradle.  I have everything close to the way I want it, and im trying to build the eclipse files.  The problem is when i run the command `gradle eclipse` the eclipse plugin creates the eclipse files for the bottom level project, but not the subprojects.
my folders look like this

```
foobar
--ear
--ejb
--spring
--web
build.gradle
settings.gradle
```

even if i do `gradle ejb:eclipse` everything appears to run correctly, i get the notices that the eclipse tasks ran in the console, but no files in the ejb project.

here is my build.gradle.  What am i doing wrong?

```
configure(allprojects){ project ->
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'

    sourceCompatibility = 1.6

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: "C:/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/8.5/plugins/", include: [
            'com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar', 
            'com.ibm.ws.wsadie/marshall.jar'
            ])
        compile fileTree(dir: "C:/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/8.5/runtimes/", include: [
            'com.ibm.jaxrs.thinclient_8.5.0.jar',
            'com.ibm.jaxws.thinclient_8.5.0.jar',
            'com.ibm.ws.ejb.embeddableContainer_8.5.0.jar',
            'com.ibm.ws.ejb.thinclient_8.5.0.jar',
            'com.ibm.ws.jpa.thinclient_8.5.0.jar',
            'com.ibm.ws.orb_8.5.0.jar'
            ])
    }

    ext {
        easymockVersion = '3.3.1'
        jeeVersion = '6.0'
        junitVersion = '4.12'
        springVersion = '4.1.5.RELEASE'
        swaggerVersion = '1.3.12'
    }
}

project('ear'){
    description = "The EAR Project"

    apply plugin: 'ear'

    dependencies {
        deploy project(':ejb')
        deploy project(':spring')
        deploy project(path: ':web', configuration: 'archives')
    }
}

project('ejb'){
    description = "The EJB Project"

    dependencies {
        compile project(':spring')
    }
}

project('spring'){
    description = "The Spring BL Logic"

    dependencies {
        runtime "org.springframework:spring-jdbc:$springVersion"

        testCompile "junit:junit:$junitVersion"
        testCompile "org.easymock:easymock:$easymockVersion"
        testCompile "org.springframework:spring-test:$springVersion"
    }
}

project('web'){
    description = "The REST layer"
    apply plugin: 'war'

    dependencies {
        compile project(':ejb')

        runtime "com.wordnik:swagger-annotations:$swaggerVersion"
        runtime "com.wordnik:swagger-core_2.10:$swaggerVersion"
        runtime "com.wordnik:swagger-jaxrs_2.10:$swaggerVersion"
    }
}
```

This is the output i get.  It tells me the plugin fired for the subprojects but i can't figure out why it doesn't create any files

```
$ gradle eclipse
:eclipseClasspath
:eclipseJdt
:eclipseProject
:eclipse
:ear:eclipseClasspath
:ear:eclipseJdt
:ear:eclipseProject
:ear:eclipse
:ejb:eclipseClasspath
:ejb:eclipseJdt
:ejb:eclipseProject
:ejb:eclipse
:spring:eclipseClasspath
:spring:eclipseJdt
:spring:eclipseProject
:spring:eclipse
:web:eclipseClasspath
:web:eclipseJdt
:web:eclipseProject
:web:eclipse
```